# memory leak caused by initialize method of YouTubePlayer.Provider

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-youtube-api

Using Eclipse Memory Analyzer i discovered that if I go back and forth between 2 activity (e.g. A and B), although onDestroy method of activity B is called, GC never removes it from memory, so I have multiple instances of Activity B in memory.
I found that the problem is in initialize method called on YouTubePlayerFragment instance.
Here is the code:

```
YouTubePlayerFragment ytpf =(YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);

ytpf.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY,this);
```

`this` is the the activity where fragment takes place, and implements `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener`.

How can I release the callback passed on initialize method?

I tried to call `youtubePlayer.release()` but the problem remains.

Comment: did you solve the issue? With that memory leak YouTube player remains unusable

Comment: Having the same issue, has it been reported to Google ?

Comment: I don't use YouTubePlayerFragment anymore, I'm actually using a custom fragment that launch an Intent with YouTubeStandalonePlayer

Comment: This still exists, damn google

Comment: This STILL exists...Can't believe how much time I wasted on it, only to discover it's a bug.

Comment: Any updates for this error

Answer (score 1):

I was hit by this leak this week. It seems that Google still hasn't fixed it, regardless of the [ticket's status](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175499). I made some tests on my initial project, on which the leak is causing an OOM, and on the [demo project by Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads). My observations are :

- It's not the listener `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener` that is causing the leak. When calling `YouTubePlayerFragment.initialize()`, there are calls in `YouTubePlayerFragment` getting a reference to the activity that is hosting the fragment. So no luck in trying to call `initialize()` with an empty and static listener when the fragment is being stopped, hoping that the reference would be cleaned up.
- While there is a leak for sure, it seems that at some point, there is a cleanup being done. I would go to 18 instances of the same activity, and then the count would drop down to 8 instances. So I guess that for the majority of the cases the leak could go unnoticed.
- `YouTubePlayerFragment`& `YouTubePlayerView`, same leaks.

I don't see any workaround this. I guess I will have to use another implementation, based on a webview like this one : https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

Comment: Any workarounds